# Is it okay to have just one model for questions and comments?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I want to use methods for questions and comments like `add_question(), get_all_quests(), add_comment()` etc. in just one model. Why, you might ask, because I have one function there `validate_html()`, which validates html code and I want to validate it in both comments and questions (because people can enter html code in comments and questions). So, is it ok to do like that?

Comment: I would simply make a validator class and instantiate it within all the classes that need to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function validate_html() should go into separate system of library. So along with MVC there should be a fourth level called Library which can be shared across the application

Please refer my answer here: [Proper place to put logic in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745895/proper-place-to-put-function-in-mvc/5746008#5746008) for more info.

```
function add_question()
{
// do stuff
$library->validate_html();
}

function add_comment()
{
// do stuff
$library->validate_html();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply - No. The whole point of a model is that it should encapsulate the data in relation to that specific element e.g. all the data about a question, and all the data about a comment.

However, you also want to maximise code re-use. The nicest way to do this would be to create a Validator class which contains the validate_html() method. This can then be used in your controller - if you are doing MVC - to validate the models.